# Hardware compatibility of Ubuntu20 with Nvidia RTX 2080

Tags: nvidia

I hope all is going well

I am going to purchase below CPU with below configuration:-
1)Nvidia RTX 2080 super 8 GB
2)MSI B365M MORTOR
3)Processor I7,9th generation.9700f
4)RAM 32 GB–Kingston X 2
5)Primary SSD 500 GB
6)secondary Sata HDD 2TB
7)cabinet spec 01

Now My problem is means I have a doubt about installation of Ubuntu 20 version on above configuration.
"Can Ubutu20 supports and works on above CPU configuration with given Graphic card and Motherboard with full functionality ?"
Please suggest and Help me I am going to purchase this CPU soon can it works with charms with Ubuntu20

Comment: Please have a look at above all CPU configuration Specially Motherboard and Graphics card I want to know if that works with Ubuntu20 or not

Comment: There is no "Ubuntu20" release. And shopping recommendations are off-topic. But I see no reason why it won't work.